# Sync branch with master and keep branch alive in git

Tags: git, version-control

I have following situation:

```
master      A - D - E
              \
feature         B - C
```

and I would like to go to this:

```
master      A - D - E
                     \
feature               B - C
```

How can I achieve such result in git / sourcetree? Note, that both branches have theirs counterparts on origin and are used by others.

Comment: you can merge or you can rebase, but both will change the C visible to others by adding changes from D and E.  Or make a new local copy of the feature branch, and change it just for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It would normally by a git remote master, but since the branches are already shared (changing the history of `feature` would be bad), it is best to merge master in feature and go on in the `feature` branch:

```
master      A - D - E
              \       \
feature         B - C- M - x - x ...
```

If you really want a branch starting from `E`, make a new one, and [cherry-pick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994491/6309) the commit from `feature`. Then push that new branch.